# SQL Query Optimization for Cross Apply

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Problem: Get the details of the last transaction for all customers who have had no transactions since 2015-06-30. Transactions not to be of type 2.

I came up with the below. While it gives the result needed, it seems inefficient. Any improvements?

```SQL
    SELECT
          LastCustTrans.CustAccount 
        , LastCustTrans.DimID       
        , LastCustTrans.TransDate       
    FROM
    (   SELECT      CustTrans.CustAccount
        FROM        @CustTrans AS [CustTrans]
        WHERE       CustTrans.TransType != 2
        GROUP BY    CustTrans.CustAccount
        HAVING      MAX(CustTrans.TRANSDATE) < DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE())
    )   AS [LastCust]
        CROSS APPLY 
        (   SELECT TOP 1 *
            FROM @CustTrans AS [CUSTTRANS]
            WHERE   CustTrans.CustAccount   = LastCust.CustAccount
                AND CustTrans.TransType != 2
            ORDER BY CustTrans.TransDate DESC 
        ) AS LastCustTrans
    ORDER BY LastCustTrans.CustAccount
```

***Sample Data:***

```SQL
    DECLARE @CustTrans TABLE
    (     CustAccount   NVARCHAR(3)
        , TransDate     DATE
        , TransType     INT
        , DimID         NVARCHAR(3)
        , Amt           NUMERIC(32, 16)
        , RECID         INT
    )

    INSERT INTO @CustTrans 
        VALUES    ('C01', '2015-06-15', 1, 'D01', 10, 1) 
                , ('C01', '2015-11-15', 1, 'D01', 15, 2)
                , ('C01', '2015-04-15', 1, 'D02', 20, 3)
                , ('C02', '2015-05-15', 1, 'D03', 25, 4)
                , ('C02', '2015-03-15', 1, 'D04', 30, 5)
                , ('C02', '2015-12-15', 2, 'D03', 35, 6)
```

***Expected Output***

```
    CustAccount DimID   TransDate
    C02         D03     2015-05-15
```

Comment: Added expected output based on given sample data.

Comment: What is the TOP 1 needed for? Without ORDER BY you'll get any qualifying row.

Comment: sorry when creating this sample code, forgot to copy over the `ORDER BY`

Comment: but if you remove Order by it's working fine just see the execution plan @147

Comment: @mohan111 - that's only because the sample data is ordered to begin with. For actual data, forgetting the `ORDER BY` in a query with `TOP` will unpredictable results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give this a try:

```
SELECT CustAccount, DimID, TransDate
FROM (
  SELECT CustAccount, DimID, TransDate,
         MAX(TransDate) OVER (PARTITION BY CustAccount) AS maxDate,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustAccount 
                            ORDER BY TransDate DESC) AS rn
  FROM CustTrans
  WHERE TransType != 2) AS t
WHERE t.rn = 1 AND maxDate < DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE())
```

The problem with query is propably due to the correlation of the `CROSS APPLY` query. The above query uses exclusively window functions, so it is propably more efficient.

Comment: Looks good... lemme check by porting it to the actual query before I mark as valid answer.